# Returns the new array of combined values with one old value

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am using Lodash for combining two arrays to return new values,

example,

```
var lastValue = [{"id": 5, "view": {"id": 2932, "name": "Available"}, "rowAttribute": "last value 1"}, {"id": 6, "view": {"id": 2933, "name": "Active"}, "rowAttribute": "last value 2"}]

var updatedValue = [{"view": {"id": 2932, "name": "Available"}, "rowAttribute": "updated value 1"}, {"view": {"id": 2934, "name": "inactive"}, "rowAttribute": "updated value 2"}]
```

I am using unionBy like,

```
_.unionBy(lastValue, updatedValue, 'view.id');
```

and I am getting like,

```
[{"view": {"id": 2932, "name": "Available"}, "rowAttribute": "updated value 1"}, {"id": 6, "view": {"id": 2933, "name": "Active"}, "rowAttribute": "last value 2"}, {"view": {"id": 2934, "name": "inactive"}, "rowAttribute": "updated value 2"}]
```

My expectation is like,

```
 [
  {
    "id": 5,
    "view": {
      "id": 2932,
      "name": "Available"
    },
    "rowAttribute": "updated value 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "view": {
      "id": 2933,
      "name": "Active"
    },
    "rowAttribute": "last value 2"
  },
  {
    "view": {
      "id": 2934,
      "name": "inactive"
    },
    "rowAttribute": "updated value 2"
  }
]
```

I want combined values of both the array. if view.id is/are available in updatedValue then it should return with updated value with Id else same from both the arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to get the desired result

```js
var lastValue = [
  { id: 5, view: { id: 2932, name: "Available" }, rowAttribute: "last value" },
];

var updatedValue = [
  { view: { id: 2932, name: "Available" }, rowAttribute: "updated value" },
];

const result = lastValue.map((o, i) => Object.assign({}, o, updatedValue[i]));
console.log(result);
```

If you want to update the object with `view.id`

```js
var lastValue = [
  { id: 5, view: { id: 2932, name: "Available" }, rowAttribute: "last value" },
];

var updatedValue = [
  { view: { id: 2932, name: "Available" }, rowAttribute: "updated value" },
];

const result = lastValue.map((o, i) =>
  Object.assign(
    {},
    o,
    updatedValue.find((obj) => obj.view.id === o.view.id)
  )
);
console.log(result);
```

You can even optimise the result using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as

```js
var lastValue = [
  { id: 5, view: { id: 2932, name: "Available" }, rowAttribute: "last value" },
];

var updatedValue = [
  { view: { id: 2932, name: "Available" }, rowAttribute: "updated value" },
];

const dict = new Map(updatedValue.map((o) => [o.view.id, o]));

const result = lastValue.map((o, i) => Object.assign({}, o, dict.get(o.view.id)));
console.log(result);
```

**Updated#4** If you want to join the array then you have to use `find` and `Object.assign`

```js
var lastValue = [
  {
    id: 5,
    view: { id: 2932, name: "Available" },
    rowAttribute: "last value 1",
  },
  { id: 6, view: { id: 2933, name: "Active" }, rowAttribute: "last value 2" },
];

var updatedValue = [
  { view: { id: 2932, name: "Available" }, rowAttribute: "updated value 1" },
  { view: { id: 2934, name: "inactive" }, rowAttribute: "updated value 2" },
];

updatedValue.forEach((o) => {
  const objInLastValue = lastValue.find((obj) => obj.view.id === o.view.id);
  if (objInLastValue) Object.assign(objInLastValue, o);
  else lastValue.push(o);
});

console.log(lastValue);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: can I check with view.id instead of index? if view.id match, then return updated value else last value only.

Comment: Yup, you can but first you have to find that element in the `updatedValue` array. Let me updated the answer

Comment: sorry your answer is correct only but I gave you the wrong information. Please see again I updated the question.

Comment: what have you updated?

Comment: I want combined values of both the array. if view.id is/are available in updatedValue then it should return with updated value with Id else same from both the arrays.

Comment: Answer updated. Have a look and see is this what you want

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response, it's working as expected.